# Android: How to remove overflow menu icon tooltip?

Tags: android, icons, tooltip, overflow-menu

In Android, when you `onLongClick` an overflow menu item icon, a tooltip of its title will appear.

I've tried setting the menu title to blank, but a blank tooltip will pop up.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_icon"
        android:title="Icon Title"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_myicon"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

Notes:

• I'm using app namespace because Android Studio is telling me to use it due to having `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` as my theme. I've tried android namespace. Doesn't work either.

• My menu is created in a `Fragment` with `hasOptionsMenu(true)`.

• My ActionBar is a `Toolbar`.

How can I remove this tooltip if it's possible? Thanks!

Comment: remove title attribute from item for that

Comment: I've tried it will just give you a blank tooltip as well.

Comment: the only way to do this is up is with
android:showAsAction="withText"

Comment: and use title as blank

Answer (score 0):

the only way to do this is up is with android:showAsAction="withText" and set Title as =""

For onLongClickListener:

```
final MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
            searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem);
            searchView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but this does not work. `android:showAsAction="withText"` will force my menu item to be only shown as a text item. Together with `android:title=""` will result in a blank text menu item. I've tried `android:showAsAction="always|withText"`, but this does not work either.

Comment: u can override menuitem onlongclick and then do nothing in it to not show tooltip

Comment: `MenuItem` does not have a OnLongClickListener. Calling `MenuItem.getActionView()` is always null too...

Comment: they have an onLongClick listener

Comment: android:showAsAction="withText" is working for me i dont know why it isnt working for you

Comment: hmm..Are you use AppCompat theme?

Comment: I updated my question with my specific configuration for the menu. Also can you link me to the doc that shows MenuItem's OnLongClickListener? Appreciate it ty!

Comment: final MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
   searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem);
            searchView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    return false;
                }
            });

Comment: Ok, I think I'm about to give up. `getActionView()` always returns `null.`

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. In the java class remove the 
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
and the job will be done. If no remove this also from the java class 
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)

Comment: This just removes my entire menu completely. Technically that does remove the tooltip lol.

Comment: Remove the public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) only.